# Credit for republished writing

Tags: writing, cv

I recently had an essay published in a semi-academic journal. It was widely shared and consequently got picked up by a few other online magazines who republished it. How do I list this on a CV? As separate publications with the title, or a note explaining the situation?

Comment: Was it peer reviewed?

Comment: No, not peer reviewed. It was a commissioned piece in a magazine that discusses theory.

Comment: _It...got picked up by a few other online magazines who *republished it*_ (emphasis added). This surely violates copyright, which (respectable) magazines would surely not do. Have I misunderstood?

Answer (score 1):

People usually add press coverage in a note after the publication eg
C. Xavier “On Human Genetic Mutation”, thesis, 1975
Press Coverage: CNN, BBC

Etc